# CTE Row Number Partitioning

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm struggling to get to the correct logic with regards to my CTE.

**Some background information:**

A task is generated in the system for all the members that has the sales role. This basically inserts multiple records into my `Task` table. The Task tabel has amongst other, the following columns: `AssignedTo` and `RequestedBy` - whereby `AssignedTo` will have each of the sale members Id's. Currently all the sales people can see the task, because no one has claimed it:

```
ApprovalStatusId EntityType     EntityId    AssignedTo      RequestedBy
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 4             | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 9             | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 17            | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 26            | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 39            | 6
```

Now that a task has been generated for each sales person, one of them, doesn't matter who, can react on the task, which will change the `AssignedTo` as well as the task status:

```
ApprovalStatusId  EntityType    EntityId    AssignedTo    RequestedBy
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 4         | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 9         | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 17        | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 26        | 6
18               | FooBar       | 281       | 39        | 6
17               | FooBar       | 281       | 26        | 6
1                | FooBar       | 281       | 6         | 6
```

As you can see from the above table, user 26 reacted to the task and changed the status. Once that was done, the system redirected the task back to the original requested, which was user 6 - the status also changed to indicate this action.

**Issues:**

1. Currently, only one user (Id 4) sees the task assigned to all sales users

**What I've tried:**

To address #1:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT task.*, stat.Name AS StatusName,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId, EntityType ORDER BY ModifiedData DESC) AS rn
   FROM dbo.Task task
   INNER JOIN dbo.ApprovalStatus stat on task.ApprovalStatusId = stat.ApprovalStatusId
)

SELECT *
FROM cte    
WHERE AssignedTo = @resourceId 
AND StatusName like 'Pending%'
AND rn = 1
```

So one of the issues with this piece of SQL is `AND rn = 1`, because this is what causes the issue raised in point 1, but if I remove it and the status changes, it won't get the newest task item. On the other-hand, it also causes this issue.

I've also tried to change the partitioning to: `PARTITION BY EntityId, EntityType, AssignedTo ORDER BY ModifiedData DESC`, but the problem with that is, it will produce a `rn` that is equal to 1 in most cases, which won't produce the correct result based on the sales group.

[Update]:

Task Table Definition:
[image]

Sample Data:

```
Comments     InsertDate                     ModifiedData                CommentUserId   ApprovalStatusId    EntityType      EntityId     TenantId    AssignedTo  RequestedBy
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |4              |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |6              |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |9              |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |17             |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |26             |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |39             |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |67             |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |10073          |42
...         |   2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    2017-03-20 11:18:06.343|    NULL            |   18              |   FooBar     |    75      |7              |10164          |42
```

Desired output:

The sales user that claimed the task should be the only one that can see it. In other words, the sales user should be able to see this record (visible in second table example) - all the other sales users should see nothing

```
17               | FooBar       | 281       | 26        | 6
```

Comment: Can you please add the full schema and some test data that you are working with here?  Your question does not - for example - have a `ModifiedData` column anywhere in your sample data.  Could you please also add a desired output based on the sample data, rather than trying to explain it.

Comment: Hey @iamdave, thanks for the reply. To be honest, it's quite involved, so I'll try to break it down the best I can.

Comment: How are you ordering this data as every date value here is the same?  Is this just a typo on your part?

Comment: No, this is not a typo. I have a sproc that insert tasks for all sales resources on a certain system event. So it will insert the same system event for all of them - Status 18 would indicate pending pre-approval

Comment: @iamdave many thanks - it seems like the answer posted by SqlZim did the trick: `dense_rank()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question would be better if you showed your desired results, but I think what you might want to do is consider using a different `ranking` window function other than [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), such as [**`dense_rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT task.*, stat.Name AS StatusName,
         dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId, EntityType ORDER BY ModifiedData DESC) AS dr
   FROM dbo.Task task
   INNER JOIN dbo.ApprovalStatus stat on task.ApprovalStatusId = stat.ApprovalStatusId
)

SELECT *
FROM cte    
WHERE AssignedTo = @resourceId 
AND StatusName like 'Pending%'
AND dr = 1
```

When the multiple records are initially inserted into your `task` table, instead of your cte returning:

```
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| ApprovalStatusId | EntityType | EntityId | AssignedTo | RequestedBy | rn |
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+----+
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |          4 |           6 |  1 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |          9 |           6 |  2 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |         17 |           6 |  3 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |         26 |           6 |  4 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |         39 |           6 |  5 |
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+----+
```

It would return:

```
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| ApprovalStatusId | EntityType | EntityId | AssignedTo | RequestedBy | dr |
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+----+
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |          4 |           6 |  1 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |          9 |           6 |  1 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |         17 |           6 |  1 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |         26 |           6 |  1 |
|               18 | FooBar     |     281  |         39 |           6 |  1 |
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+----+
```

So that would solve issue #1, where only one of the users is seeing the pending task.

Comment: Holy smokes ... never even knew about `dense_rank()` - Busy with implementation to check if it can word - Thanks